# Why no ROSCON 2013 videos on youtube?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Youtube works more reliably in more places for me, especially on mobile devices.
I've found the links to vimeo on http://roscon.ros.org/2013/?page_id=14- couldn't there be a OSRF youtube channel with the videos duplicated from vimeo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/96886/why-no-roscon-2013-videos-on-youtube?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2013-11-01

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2013-11-13**:
While I +1ed, Vimeo Android app works fine with me btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Vimeo was chosen for the cleaner interface and the ability to host the videos without ads everywhere. Dual hosting it ends up being just twice as much work.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2014-01-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) on 2014-01-28**:
But most people search on youtube for ros related videos.Many would have watched them if they were in youtube.